# ActionBar to show icons, but it shows the menu commands instead

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I 've an action bar (from support.v7) with some Tabs, so far so good.

The problem is with the menus.

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:name="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

   <item
        android:id="@+id/action_m1"
         android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_chat"
        android:title=""/>



    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_m2"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_merge"
        android:title="">
    </item>

</menu>
```

"always" is ignored. It never shows as an Action, it's shown only when I press the "menu". This happens even if I don't have any tabs loaded, and there is plenty of space.

What could be wrong, am I missing some call on the ActionBar?

Best Regards.

Comment: tltle seems empty, did you try with some title? but im not sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the android namespace for the menu items when using the support library `ActionBar`. Instead, you need to prefix the attribute with your custom namespace:

```
// in the menu xml file
xmlns:name="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_m1"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    name:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_chat"
    android:title=""/>
```

You can read more in the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems).

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: @Michael Do you actually use the new namespace? In my example I have `name:showAsAction="always"`.

Comment: Yes I just noticed it... thanks :)

Comment: A think if you have the fisical menu button in your phone or your emulator, it influences the actionbar menu.